# How to resolve this compiler error "Cannot convert the expression's type '$T6' to type '$T7??'"

Tags: swift

Here is my code :

```
  let aString = "ABC"
  let destImage = myCell.myitemImage?.image
  myClass?.myFunc(aString, destImage);  // error here
```

On second line, I get compiler error  "Cannot convert the expression's type '$T6' to type '$T7??'"

Here is the definition of myFunc:

```
class myClass {

    func loadImage(aString : String, inout destImage: UIImage) {

        // some logic about aString
        // Then I create an UIImage class here and set it to destination (pass in as argument)
       var image = UIImage(data: data)
       destImage = image;
    }
}
```

Comment: is this your real code? where is `myFunc`? is `myClass` a class not variable?

Comment: Which version of XCode?

Comment: I think myFunc is loadImage functioon in myClass in this context. myCell.myitemImage?.image return optional type UIImage?. But you have type UIImage as input parameter in function func loadImage(aString : String, inout destImage: UIImage). You must put "!" after destImage like this: myClass?.myFunc(aString, destImage!);   But in last version of Xcode it should have been a help message from IDE to fix this problem. May be you have the previous versin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several things:

1) You are passing a constant ("let value") to an `inout` parameter.  You need to pass a `var` so that it can be changed.

2) You need to put `&` in front of the `inout` variable.

3) You need to decide what you are going to do if `myCell.myitemImage` is nil.

4) I assume you want to set `myCell.myitemImage?.image` to the new image.

Taking these into account, I suggest:

```
if myCell.myitemImage != nil {
    myclass?.loadImage(aString, destImage: &myCell.myitemImage!.image)
}
```

---

If all your `loadImage` function does with `destImage` is assign a new image to it, I suggest you consider changing your `loadImage` function to return the `UIImage`:

```
func loadImage(aString: String) -> UIImage {
    // some logic about aString
    // Then I create an UIImage class here and return it
    let image = UIImage(data: data)
    return image
}
```

Then it is much clearer that you are loading an image and where you are assigning it:

```
if myCell.myitemImage != nil {
    myCell.myitemImage!.image = myclass?.loadImage(aString)
}
```