# Xcode 6.1 componentsSeparatedByCharacterInSet Compiler Error

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

to be able to deploy an App onto an iPhone with IOS 8.1 I updated Xcode 6.0.1 to 6.1.

With this step I got a couple of compiler errors, e.g.

```
var lines : NSArray = mydata.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacter.newlineCharacterSet())
```

Error:

> Cannot convert the expression's type '$T6??' to type '[AnyObject]'

What is '$T6??

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25904908/how-to-resolve-this-compiler-error-cannot-convert-the-expressions-type-t6-t?rq=1) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that I need an explicit cast **as [NSArray]**

```
var lines : NSArray = mydata.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacter.newlineCharacterSet()) as [NSArray]
```

But still don't know, what '$T6??' stands for. Google did not help.

Comment: '$T6??' is Swift name mangling, see [Swift Name Mangling](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-08-15-swift-name-mangling.html) by Gwynne Raskind